# Git new remote branches

Tags: git, bonobo

I tried to create a new branch in git. The new branch name is "1.0.0". Why is that after I push it into remote, the branches display become '1.0.0.x-dev'. Why is it adding 'x-dev' at the back? How can I have it to be original name '1.0.0' on the remote repository?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your remote? I guess it's not GitHub because I just tried this and it worked, it didn't rename the branch. So you must be using something else. And that something else seems to rename branches with this kind of name.

Comment: @Janos Thanks a lot for respond to my question. I am using local bonobo git server. Is there any command I need to put at the back?

Comment: Did you try to force the remote name branch? `git push -u origin 1.0.0:1.0.0`