# Composer Releases Name

Tags: composer-php, satis

Why is that the composer repository generated by Satis always add "dev" into the releases?

For example:

1. If my branch name is "master", it will become "dev-master"
2. If my branch name is "1.0.0", it will become "1.0.0.x-dev"
3. If my branch name is "1.0.1m", it will become "dev-1.0.1m"

How can I prevent it adding the extra "dev" into the release?

Comment: Just a question; is this not a dupe of this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398643/git-new-remote-branches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dev` prefix or suffix is added to branch names to clearly identify them as such to both users and composer. They must be treated differently because they are not fixed point-in-time snapshots like tags are.

If you create a git or svn tag called `1.0.0` then the composer version will still be `1.0.0`.

Since the branch `1.0` for example can be the source for the `1.0.0` tag, then the `1.0.1` tag, and so on, it is suffixed and shown as `1.0-dev`, which shows it is under development and not a real release.